# auto increment id with respect to the rest of the primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
| PK | Col Name | Type |
|----+----------+------|
| X  | ParentId | int
| X  | Id       | int
```

I tried to set `Id` to be the identity, and ParentId is set on the parent table. What I was hoping the data would look like would be:

```
| ParentId | Id |
|----------+----|
| 1        | 1  |
| 1        | 2  |
| 1        | 3  |
| 2        | 1  |
| 2        | 2  |
| 3        | 1  |
```

but instead it looks like:

```
| ParentId | Id |
|----------+----|
| 1        | 1  |
| 1        | 2  |
| 1        | 3  |
| 2        | 4  |
| 2        | 5  |
| 3        | 6  |
```

which makes sense in hindsight. Is the desired effect achievable in some way?

Comment: Identitys are always unique - so no, you cant have a single identity and have it have identical values, sorry.

Comment: Do not set autoincrement on child table. Instead create your PK on both `ParentId` and `Id` in the child table and then fill its values manually, or through a trigger.

Comment: @dotNET, that's what I as expecting. I'll go the trigger route.

Comment: Really, "FOO" as table name.

Comment: @Charles - Have you checked my answer? Problem solved?

Comment: @Md.SumanKabir, sorry, just saw it. It was solved via Patrick and dotNET comments... use triggers. I just forgot to delete the question.That said you went the extra mile and the produced sql to correct the issue. I'll accept that for you.

Comment: @KashifQureshi, edited it just for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the desired output from only the `ParentId`, i also suggest this, you can use this :

```
select ParentId, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY parentid order by parentid) as Id
from Foo
```

[SQL HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/053e5/4)

But if you still want to use in the table, you can create a `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger on your table, here is the trigger you can use :

```
create trigger dbo.trInsertFoo on dbo.Foo instead of insert
as begin
    insert into dbo.Foo
            (ParentId, Id)
    select  ParentId,
            Id =
            isnull( (select max(Id)
                    from    dbo.Foo
                    where   ParentId = i.ParentId), 0) +
            row_number() over (partition by ParentId order by (select 1))
    from    inserted i;
end;
```

**Simplified version of the above trigger**

```
create trigger dbo.trInsertFoo on dbo.Foo instead of insert
as begin
    insert into dbo.Foo
            (ParentId, Id)
    select  ParentId,
            Id =
            (select isnull(max(Id), 0) + 1 from dbo.Foo where ParentId = i.ParentId)
    from    inserted i;
end;
```

But this one will not work for batch insert like :

```
INSERT INTO Foo (ParentId) VALUES (1), (1), (1), (2), (2), (3)`
```